# How to write multiple equalsIgnoreCase() in one statement?

Tags: java, string

Is there a way to implement something like this without giving operand errors?

```
if (check.equalsIgnoreCase("a"|| "e" || "i" || "o" || "u")) {}
```

Comment: Try using regex to check /[aAeEiIoOuU]/g

Comment: write a method that compares the string and returns the result as boolean then call that inside the if statement. `boolean compare(String s) { return s.equalsIgnoreCase("a") || s.equalsIgnoreCase("e") || s.equalsIgnoreCase("i") || s.equalsIgnoreCase("o") || s.equalsIgnoreCase("u") }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logical operators only work on booleans, you're trying to use them on Strings. Do this instead:

```
if(check.equalsIgnoreCase("a")
        || check.equalIgnoreCase("e")
        || check.equalIgnoreCase("i")
        || check.equalIgnoreCase("o")
        || check.equalIgnoreCase("u")) {
    // Your code here
}
```

Also you can flip the expression to avoid null-checks: `"a".equalsIgnoreCase(check)`.

You could also look into regular expressions which would make the code a lot more compact. But as you say you're just starting, I think this will do for now.

Comment: This is the  kind of answer I was looking for as a beginner, thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome. Could you accept my answer then? ;-)

Comment: Yes ... but "avoiding null checks" is often a bad idea.  In many contexts, it is better to understand where the `null` values come from and *eradicate them there* ... rather than scattering null checks (or null check avoidance) throughout your codebase.

Comment: @StephenC what if I am creating a library for others? Is it ok to make my code fail safe or let users deal with NPE?

Comment: @onkarruikar always let users deal with NPE.

Comment: Agreed.  What you should do is to document your library APIs to make it clear when `null` is allowed, and throw NPEs when a method is called with a `null` in violation of the contract.  And design your APIs to only accept a `null` argument when it has a clear meaning.  (That is how the Java SE's behave!!)

Comment: So called "fail safe" handling of `null` is better described as *error hiding*.  In the long term, it leads to obscure and hard to diagnose bugs.  (And verbose code ... or stilted code.)  An unexpected `null` is evidence of a bug.  Bugs need to be fixed, not hidden.  (IMO!)

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 answers already. Using [logical operators](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66406272/8430155) and [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66406295/8430155).

Here is another approach using [`.indexOf(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)).

```
if (“aeiou”.indexOf(check) >= 0) {
    // your code here
 }
```

Comment: You mean `“aeiouAEIOU”`, I think.

Comment: @StephenC If we're not restricted to ASCII, these two also match `.equalsIgnoreCase("i")`: "[`İ`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0130)" (LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I WITH DOT ABOVE) and
"[`ı`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0131)" (LATIN SMALL LETTER DOTLESS I)

Answer (score 3):

```java
if (Stream.of("a", "e", "i", "o", "u").anyMatch(check::equalsIgnoreCase)) {
  // ...
}
```

This will return true if any of the elements in the given [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html) return true for `check.equalsIgnoreCase(element)`, where `element` is the stream element.

This calls the [`anyMatch(Predicate)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch(java.util.function.Predicate)) method against the stream consisting of the five strings.  Since `equalsIgnoreCase` takes a string and returns a boolean, `check::equalsIgnoreCase` can be used as a [method reference lambda expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) as a `Predicate<String>`.

Comment: Elegant, but not efficient.

Comment: For this exact specific check, sure, though depending on the use case it's likely to be efficient enough.  Plus without greater context, it's hard to tell whether it's truly the vowel check that's important to the asker, or whether it's the general pattern of "multiple equalsIgnoreCase() in one statement?" posed by the question title.  This solution is scalable and generalizable where a regex or manual `||` check may or may not be, depending on the types of data involved.

Comment: Yea ... maybe.  Though for elegance *and* efficiency *and* scalability I prefer the `indexOf` approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can also consider [String.matches](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches-java.lang.String-) which takes a regular expression and tells that the string match it or not:

```java
if (check.matches("a|e|i|o|u"))
```

Or, for case insensitivity:

```java
if (check.matches("(?i)a|e|i|o|u"))
```

This is certainly overkill if you just need to match a single letter in a string, and the correct answer for your question [was given](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66406272/8541499) by @geanakuch, so please accept it. But this solution can be useful in the other cases, when you need to deal with more complex patterns in strings comparison.